# Azure MS SQL Import to MySQL via Workbench - No schema?

Tags: sql-server, azure, mysql-workbench

I'm having a very difficult time migrating a database between MS SQL and MySQL.

What i've done so far is setup Azure account and launched SQL server, managed to import data from SQL file.

After long battle I thought it's over, however I use MySQL workbench to try and import the data, all connections seem fine, however onc eit finishes retrieving the schema, it's empty? I'm using the main user it seems, but I'm guessing it's still permission issue, anyone could guide me in the right direction?

Log from workbench:

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connecting to Mssql@azure test 2...
Opening ODBC connection to DSN=azure test 2;DATABASE=;UID=scoding;PWD=XXXX...
Connected to Mssql@azure test 2, 12.0.2000.8
Connect to source DBMS done
Check target DBMS connection...
- Connecting to target...
Check target DBMS connection done
Retrieve schema list from source....
- Checking connection...
- Fetching catalog names...
- Fetching schema names...
- Finished
Retrieve schema list from source finished
Finished performing tasks.
```

EDIT

As suggested by someone, somewhere, I downloaded SQLyog tool, that one picks up the schema, and imports tables, however brakes on larger tables(20k rows) and also trial only allows 2 tables at once, so need to figure this one out.